# Why is my shell only detecting return codes between 0 - 255?

Tags: c++, bash, shell, zsh, return-code

Take the following C++ program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){exit(-1);}
```

When I run this program in either `zsh`, `bash`, or `sh`, I get the following results:

```
$ ./test
$ echo $?
255
$
```

---

If I run:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main(){exit(256);}
```

it produces the following:

```
$ ./test
$ echo $?
0
$
```

---

Is it normal for a shell to interpret return codes between 0 - 255?
Is it possible to produce values outside of this range?

Comment: It is normal for shell in Linux. It should be possible to produce values outside of this range  by creating your own OS.

Comment: Linux typically only stores the low 8 bits from a return value, and it communicates return statuses as 16-bit values containing either a return value or a signal number.

Comment: make sence since the OS might be getting the lower bits from the return code, which are all zeroes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ allows you to return two values from `main`: `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`. Returning `EXIT_SUCCESS` is the same as returning `0`, which has the same effect as calling `std::exit(0)`.

The return value is passed back to the operating system in an implementation-defined manner, and what the OS does with the value is also implementation-defined. Finally, the semantics of returning any other value from `main` are implementation-defined, too.

C++ has nothing more to say on this subject. You need to consult your platform's documentation.

Comment: From the Open Group specifications (Posix) http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exit.html  
<< only the least significant 8 bits [of the status parameter of exit()]  shall be available to a waiting parent process >>

Comment: Note that `EXIT_SUCCESS` exists because, conceivably, you could be running on a platform which doesn't use `0` as the exit status of a successful process. `exit` is really the interface between two different standards, in this case C++ and the host platform.

Comment: @chepner - `EXIT_SUCCESS` exists to provide a parallel construct to `EXIT_FAILURE`. Returning 0 has the same effect as `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and will work correctly regardless of the OS's convention for return codes; the runtime system will map 0 into whatever value is appropriate.

Comment: Huh, I figured the identifier would be the abstraction, not the value itself.